How in livewire to pass locale parameter with #[Url] defined?
Looking at the manual, I want to define 2 pages
exchanging data with the current locale defined, like :
Route::get('/{locale?}', [HomeController::Class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/partnership-order/{locale?}', [PartnershipOrderController::class, 'index'])->name('partnership_order.index');

and defined in component :
class PartnershipOrderDialog extends Component
{
    use WireUiActions;
    use AppCommonTrait;

    #[Url]
    public ?string $locale;   

    public function mount(): void
    {
        if(empty($this->locale)) { // if locale is not defined in url - get from the app
            $this->locale = app()->getLocale();
        }

I got the error :
Typed property App\Livewire\PartnershipOrderDialog::$locale must not be accessed before initialization

if to define :
#[Url]
public ?string $locale = '';

then $locale var is always empty and default value "en" is assigned for url like :
http://sitename/partnership-order/es

Which way is correct ?
ADDITIVE :
In the docs there is reference :

For example, if a user visits the URL
https://example.com/users?search=bob, Livewire will set the initial
value of $search to "bob".

If I try to run in the browser :
http://local-quizzes11.com/partnership-order/locale=es

Anyway checking locale value of :
public ?string $locale = '';  // config('app.locale');

public function mount(): void
{
    \Log::info($this->locale);

I see empty value.
a) In which way value from Url is assigned?
b) In routes/web.php I have :
Route::get('/partnership-order/{locale?}', [PartnershipOrderController::class, 'index'])->name('partnership_order.index');

Does it matter in this case which format is it ?
ADDITIVE # 2:
I found that if manually to run in browser url :
http://local-quizzes11.com/services/partnership-order?locale=es

with rule in web.php :
Route::get('/services/partnership-order{locale?}', [PartnershipOrderController::class, 'index'])->name('services.partnership_order.index');

the page is opened ok with valid url passed, but I do not know how to redirect from
header component with menu items in blade:
<a wire:click="redirectTo('services.partnership_order.index')"  wire:navigate


   and in component :


public function redirectTo(string $routeName) {
    return $this->redirect(route($routeName, ['locale' => $this->locale]), navigate: true);
}

where $this->locale can be changed without page reloading.
How to change ny component method(web.php url)
to redirect to page :
 http://local-quizzes11.com/services/partnership-order?locale=es
    

?

public ?string $locale = null;``` but IMHO, I would use the config.php locale as default.

Yes, in config.php there is default locale, but I need to redirect to otger page with current locale or saved url with locale set

on code :
#[Url]     public ?string $locale = config('app.locale');
I got error : Constant expression contains invalid operations ?

Please read ADDITIVE block

Please read ADDITIVE # 2 block

please try the redirectRoute() like in here. You don't need the $this->, use right away the helper redirect().

Thanks!  method $this->redirectRoute( pass the $locale  correctly, but does it support SPA? Looks like not as I see at right top of my browser that page is reload fully...
